# VueJS - Resource Plugin not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to use vue-resource. But when I do this

```
var Resource = require(‘vue-resource’);
Vue.use(Resource)
```

I get the error message in my chrome dev console:

> Uncaught InvalidValueError: app.init is not a function

When I remove both lines, all is working again
Here is the code:

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var Resource = require('vue-resource');
import GIS from './components/GIS.vue';

Vue.component('map', GIS);
Vue.use(Resource);


window.app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        address: '',
        latitude: '',
        longitude: ''
    },
    watch: {
        address: function() {
            this.requestAddress();
        }
    },
    methods: {
        init() {
            // Fire event when Maps API has been loaded
            this.$broadcast('MapsAPILoaded')
        },
        requestAddress() {
            this.$broadcast('RequestAddress')
        },
        deleteMarkers() {
            this.$broadcast('DeleteMarkers')
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thats funny.. exact same setup works for me. Although my `Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));` is directly underneath the `var Vue = require('vue');`.... why don't you try that?

Comment: You appear to have code somewhere that is calling app.init - where is that?

Comment: Aren't you missing the : function between init and ()? In other words shouldn't it be registered as init:function (){...}